# SpringBoot: Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, liquibase

In my Postgres database i have created the schema named pet and ran liquibase migration to create schema, tables and types but while starting my spring boot application.

`Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [pet_type] in table [pets]; found ["pet"."pet_type" (Types#VARCHAR)], but expecting [pet_type (Types#OTHER)]`

**PetEntity.java**

```
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Type(PostgreSQLEnumType.class)
    @Column(name = "pet_type", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "pet_type")
    private PetType petType;
```

**SQL**

```
CREATE TYPE pet_type AS ENUM ('REPTILES', 'FERRETS');

CREATE TABLE pets
(
    id                       UUID           NOT NULL,
    pet_type                 PET_TYPE NOT NULL,
);
```

in my spring boot this is the jpa configurations.

```
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        default_schema: pet
```

url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=pet&stringtype=unspecified

other information.
**Postgres Version:** PostgreSQL 14.6 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.4.0, 64-bit
**Java Version:** 17
**Hibernate:** hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62 3.6.1

Has anyone encountered this error before?

Tried changing @Column(name = "pet_type", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "pet_type") to @Column(name = "pet_type", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "pet.pet_type")

Comment: You have both `@Enumerated` and a type. Which is it? Either use `@Enumerated` and make the value a `varchar` in the database. Or use a db enum and use the type. You are now mixing 2 strategies.

Comment: Tried removing the @Enumerated as well. Same issue is still coming. I noticed that in the error it says found ["pet"."pet_type" (Types#VARCHAR)] but expecting [pet_type (Types#OTHER)] notice the in found it has pet schema but in expecteing schema is not. Does it have something to do with the issue.

Comment: what about `@ColumnTransformer(write = "?::yours_enum_type")` on `PetType` have you tried yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was missing privilege for the database user for `pet` schema.